# htaccess redirect to directory if URL contains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been googling for the past hour, but I can't seem to find any examples of what I'm after, and none of the things I've tried seem to work...

I have an existing site in root. All URLs start with `index.php?main_page`. I want to move the entire site to a new folder called shop, but need the root accessible for other files (WP in this case). So, how do I format my htaccess file so that it redirects all requests like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?main_page=XYZ
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/shop/index.php?main_page=XYZ
```

Maybe worth mentioning  - I'd like to preserve the URL requested and go to the same page, not redirect simply to shop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root, and make sure it's *before* any wordpress related rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /shop/index.php [L]
```